# How to display td tag data in Percentage Format

Tags: css, html

I was getting data in the TD tag from the backend, In the backend it was in the format of Percenatage. but, when it comes to client side it was showing 0.9888888 in this format.

Is there any attribute for td tag to change number format ?

Comment: why don't you change it directly before outputting from backend?

Comment: In the backend , Already It was in the percentage fomat like 98.8 %

Comment: `Is there any attribute for td tag to change number format ? ` answer is NO

Comment: So, How too change that format

Comment: I hope using CSS we can change it

Comment: You are not clear about what you want. Do you want the 0.9888888 to be displayed as 98.888% as text or a value for CSS?

Comment: How are you getting the data?  can you give an example of what is returned from the backend?  Also, are you just displaying the data in a `<td>`, or is the data part of a tag?

Comment: I want to be displayed as 98.888 %

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set 98.8 but you can try with commas like this

```
<td style="width:98,8%">
```

but the best way is just set it to 99% the difference is nothing

Comment: It was just changing width of the cell,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `100% width` with `minus` **`padding, margins`** and **`border`** using **`box-sizing`** property.

```
{
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

This way would be best way in-compare of assign 99% or 98.8%.